# What would right value of B and C from this code?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
class A;
    function int foo();
        int a;
        return ++a;
    endfunction
  
endclass

program tb;
    A a =new;
    int b, c;

    initial begin
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) begin
            b = a.foo();
            c = foo(); // Calls a different foo() outside of the class A
            $display("B = %0d", b);
            $display("C = %0d", c);
        end
    end

    function int foo();
        int a;
        return ++a;
    endfunction
endprogram
```

I ran this on the online EDA playground, and it printed out this result. Isn't both `a`'s getting initialised every time the function `foo` (both the functions) is called ?

```
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 2
B = 1
C = 3
B = 1
C = 4
B = 1
C = 5
B = 1
C = 6
B = 1
C = 7
B = 1
C = 8
B = 1
C = 9
B = 1
C = 10
$finish at simulation time                    0
           V C S   S i m u l a t i o n   R e p o r t
```

Can someone explain how the value of `C` is incremented here?

Comment: You might want to read [The Life of a SystemVerilog Variable](https://resources.sw.siemens.com/en-US/white-paper-the-life-of-a-systemverilog-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `foo` function is an **automatic** function.

The program `foo` function is a **static** function.

This difference causes the difference in behavior of the 2 functions.

The `int a;` line implicitly initializes `a` to 0.  In the automatic function, this initialization happens *every* time the function is called.
In the static function, this initialization only happens the *first* time the function is called.  That is why `C` increments.

In the `program`, if you explicitly declare the function as `automatic`, it will behave like the function in the class.  Change:

```
function int foo();
```

to:

```
function automatic int foo();
```

Output:

```
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
B = 1
C = 1
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 13.4.2 *Static and automatic functions*

> Functions defined within a module, interface, **program**, or package
> default to being **static**, with all declared items being statically
> allocated.

> Functions defined within a **class** are always **automatic**